# how to get the value of a cookie using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

How to get the value of a cookie in jquery. I want t be able to get the `user_first_name` and `user_last_name` from this cookie - `{"user_first_name":["Raj Subscriber"],"user_last_name":["Chudasama"]}`

```
function getCookieName(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

I tried this:

```
 const userIsLoggedIn = getCookieName('tmm_user_data');
 const b = userIsLoggedIn.user_first_name[0];
```

AND THIS:

```
 const userIsLoggedIn = getCookieName('tmm_user_data');
 const b = userIsLoggedIn.user_first_name;
```

Both return undefined

Comment: Also, just FYI, jQuery is not what you need for this. jQuery is a framework primarily for working with the DOM. To get/set cookies you need to use plain JS.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you don't know. JS doesn't have a built-in function *getCookieName()*. You would be required to make it yourself.

Eg:

```
function getCookie(cname) {
  let name = cname + "=";
  let decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  let ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(let i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    let c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```

Then you can use the function `getCookie(<name>)` to access the desired one.

Comment: I already have that declared and it still comes out with undefined